# Purify df1 by rows that have no duplicates in df2 based on several columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`, each with several columns. My goal is to modify `df1` such that it contains only rows that have duplicates in `df2` **based on several columns**. Unfortunately, I only found ways to do it based on either one or all columns. Here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(seq(1:5)),
                  c(letters[1:5]),
                  c(letters[22:26]))
colnames(df1) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")

df2 <- data.frame(c(1, 20, 30, 4, 5),
                  c(letters[1:5]),
                  c(letters[15:19]))
colnames(df2) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

Now, I want to modify `df1` such that it contains only rows that have duplicates in `df2` based on `col1` and `col2`. Thus, my goal is to get:

```
> df3
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    a    v
2    4    d    y
3    5    e    z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `merge` in base R, you can do

```
merge(df1, df2[, 1:2])
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    a    v
2    4    d    y
3    5    e    z
```

You have to drop the final column of df2 (or keep only the ID columns). By default only the IDs that match in both data.frames are kept. Also, `merge` searches for the names of the IDs that match in both data.frames (via `setdiff`), and uses them for the merge operation, which is what we want here, so we don't even have to specify the "by" or "by.x" / "by.y" arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a join option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2[1:2], on = .(col1, col2), nomatch = 0]
#   col1 col2 col3
#1:    1    a    v
#2:    4    d    y
#3:    5    e    z
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution could be

`df1[with(df1,paste0(col1,"_",col2)) %in% with(df2,paste0(col1,"_",col2)),]`

modified according to comments by @docendo discimus

Alternative solution by @docendo discimus:

`cols <- c("col1", "col2"); df1[Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, df1[cols], df2[cols])),]`

Comment: Dangerous approach in my opinion. You can think of cases where this would fail.

Comment: Can you give an example, please?

Comment: what if col1 in df1 is "1a", col 2 is "" and in df2 you have in col1 "1" and in col2 "a". By pasting those columns together, they'll look the same

Comment: A more robust approach in base (in addition to the merge approach by lmo) would be: `cols <- c("col1", "col2"); df1[Reduce(\`&\`, Map(\`==\`, df1[cols], df2[cols])),]`. But you might still have to take extra care of NAs

Answer (score 1):

We can use `semi_join` from `dplyr`. `df3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df1 %>% semi_join(df2, by = c("col1", "col2"))
```